# Access Vba - format condition not saved in Excel file (unreadable content)

Tags: excel, conditional-formatting, vba

I'm trying to create an Excel file from an Access database. I need to create some conditional formatting in the excel file. I save the file, but when I re-open the file a warning message `Unreadable content` is shown and, even repairing, the conditional formatting is lost.

I tried many options and read a lot of posts but none solving this issue.

This is involved part of the code:

```
'==========================================================================
Dim xl As Excel.Application
Dim wk3 As Workbook
Dim ws3 As Worksheet

Set xl = New Excel.Application   ' Create a excel instance
Set wk3 = xl.Workbooks.Add       ' Create a new workbook
Set ws3 = wk3.Worksheets(1)      ' Add a worksheet to the new wrkbk

...

'
' Add conditional formatting to a range
'
ws3.Range("A1:A10").FormatConditions.Add xlCellValue, xlEqual, "=TRUE"
ws3.Range("A1:A10").FormatConditions(1).Interior.Color = vbGreen

' 
' Save and close file
'
wk3.SaveAs "D:\_TOOLS\Result.xlsx" ' Save as Excel 2010 file     
wk3.Close False                    ' Close file 

' 
' Close excel and free memory
'
Set wk3 = Nothing
Set ws3 = Nothing

xl.Quit
Set xl = Nothing

'==========================================================================
```

My office version is 2010 (ver. 14.0.6112.5000  32bit). I tried many saving formats but some of them hang Access (like `xlExcel12`). Some of the others give an incompatibility error with extension during saving (like `xlExcel8`).

Any suggestions?

Answer (score 0):

You might want to try `xlWorkbookNormal` (value `-4143`) as the save format which is the Excel default (explicitly).

However, I have seen similar issues pop up when you are explicitly referencing Excel object in your code (i.e. Excel Library 14.0 is selected in the "References" of the VBA project).

The solution which has worked for me is to remove the "Excel Library" Reference and late-bound the object instead:

```
Dim xl As Object, wk3 As Object, ws3 As Object

' Create Excel object based on version installed on the machine (late bound).
Set xl = CreateObject("Excel.Application")

' Rest of your code can remain unchanged...

wk3.SaveAs "D:\_TOOLS\Result.xlsx", -4143 ' -4143 = xlWorkbookNormal
```

The downside to this during development is you will lose intellisence. So what you can do is keep the early-bound objects for development purposes, but comment them out for deployment (and vice-versa):

```
' Keep these for development.
' These require the Excel Library to be explicitly referenced.
'Dim xl As Excel.Application
'Dim wk3 As Workbook
'Dim ws3 As Worksheet

'Set xl = New Excel.Application   ' Create a excel instance


' Use for deployment.
' Remove the Excel Library reference to use this section.
Dim xl As Object, wk3 As Workbook, ws3 As Worksheet

' Create Excel object based on version installed on the machine (late bound).
Set xl = CreateObject("Excel.Application")


' Rest of your code can remain unchanged...

wk3.SaveAs "D:\_TOOLS\Result.xlsx", -4143 ' -4143 = xlWorkbookNormal
```

Comment: Unfortunately this solution doesn't work for me. 
I use the late binding when passing an object to a sub / functions 'cause otherwise there are some strange behaviours but it seems this is not the case:-(
Anything else to try?

Comment: @Wiz - I updated the answer for saving the format explicitly as the default Excel format. You didn't mention if you tried this in your OP (however it _should_ default to this if you don't specify).

Comment: I tried also with the default parameter. I'd already done with early binding but I tried it again with late binding. Not working.

Comment: Is there anything to try? Is there anyone else that had this problem in handling excel objects?